# Deploying Ethereum template on AWS?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, nodes, aws

I would like to deploy an Ethereum template (the one provided on aws website : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/blockchain-templates/latest/developerguide/blockchain-templates-ethereum.html) in a private network with 3 nodes and I would like to understand how to estimate the price. I tried using the AWS calculator but it's too complicated. I know that depends on multiple parameters , but I would like to have an average ...

Thanks for the help !

Comment: anyone used that and have some feedback? I found that it's very complicated having all those load balancing settings, bastion host, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**AWS cloud services you will use**

- EC2: miners and customer nodes
- ECS: container deployment between EC2 devices.
- VPC: network access to all resources in the cloud
- Application load balancing: access to all resources in the cloud

Cost of using the template for 2 days: $ 4.85, estimated in one month: $75.6

*Sorry: oneyearlater*

[image]